# Trying to stop AsyncTask in another Service's AsyncTask from Main Activity

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I have an Activity which implements a button click to attempt to stop my AsyncTask which is a inner class of a service and executes inside my Service.

Main Activity

```
            if (s.equals("Stop scanning")) {
                fullscan.cancel(true);
                stopService(new Intent(AnalyzeActivity.this, ScanService.class));
                txtView.setText("Scanning is stopping...");
                txtView.setText("Scanning stopped");
                but.setText("Start scanning");
            }
```

Service's AsyncTask (fullscan) doInBackground

```
if (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++ )
        if (isCancelled()) {
            return null;
        }
}
return null;
```

But it doesn't seem to get called even after calling `fullscan.cancel(true)`.

Comment: I know it's not the answer to your problem (that's why I'm commenting instead of answering), but why are you using a AsyncTask in a service? AsyncTask is meant to deploy results back to the UI, service does not have a UI.

Comment: Because i need to run a long running process in the background, my AsyncTask broadcasts the UI result via receiver inside my Activity which has a inner broadcast receiver which registers my receivers when the activity is alive.

Comment: I'm just saying, although it works, async task is not meant for that and have no reason to be used within services. Check into threads and executors. On a different note, the amount of code you put on your code is not enough for someone to help you. PLease show some more

Comment: Don't really understand what other codes i can show to better explain my question.

Comment: So how do you know that the scan is not cancelled?  And is your check for `isCancelled()` in a loop?

Comment: Yes it is a loop, the loop just continues although normally if i put my asynctask in the activity itself it works. Just that when i put it in a service it doesn't cancel itself.

Comment: @Budius - your statement regarding async tasks in Services is not correct. Async task is a very flexible framework for spinning off short-lived work. There is no need for it to be backed by a UI. Indeed the internal implementation of CursorLoaders use it I have read. CursorLoaders just serve data.

Comment: I disagree with your belief that my statement is incorrect. Check the docs: `AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.`. Do see how they say 'UI thread'? If you're running a background service you shouldn't be touching the UI thread at all. Same for CursoLoaders, from LoaderManager docs `Interface associated with an Activity or Fragment`. Activity and Fragment, that's all UI stuff not related to Services.

Comment: @Budius ultimately (in an Android world) almost everything is backed by a UI; we are writing apps after all. Using AsyncTask to talk to activity agnostic Services and expose stop start buttons under an activity is fine. AsyncTasks are a way of moving work *off the UI thread*...like any threading framework. Its good to use Android's AsyncTask since those clever folk over at google have probably thought long and hard about thread pool sizing and all that other devilish threading detail. Its not mentioned anywhere that it *must have a UI*, just don't do heavy work on the UI thread. ANR territory.

Comment: All of this explained beautifully in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: I still disagree with you and I'll point to two quotes from the docs to base on why I disagree: From Service docs `A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user`. From AsyncTask docs `AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask.`

Comment: See the difference where one says `long running` and the other says `short operations`, and pointing to the use of `java.util.concurrent` just like I said on my original comment?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24567/discussion-between-oceanlife-and-budius)

Answer (score 0):

How does your activity connect to the service? Your activity should only communicate with the underlying service binding to it (reF: [Bound Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)) and not the `Service`'s `AsyncTask`.

In your instance your local IBinder implementation should expose a `cancelTask()` method or something similar. When the activity needs to stop the work being completed under the service the activity code should get the reference to the service (this will happen when the activity connects to the service, ref: `onServiceConnected`) and then call through to the service `cancelTask`.

The Service will then stop it's own AsyncTask which it has a reference to.